# .NET Iterator to implement Iterator pattern

Tags: .net, vb.net, design-patterns

I am making use of Collections more in .NET.  I was always aware of this design pattern but I have never really used it: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternIterator.aspx.

I have used an Iterator in Java before as described here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm.  Is this Java's implementation of the Iterator pattern?

If this is Java's implementation, then is there an equivalent in .NET (specifically VB.NET)? In .NET I usually do something like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287603(v=vs.71).aspx.  I am concious that this exposes the representation of the object.

Comment: In my experience, using the [`yield` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9k7k7cf0.aspx) is quite easy to use and requires less code than a full implentation of an enumrable. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Iterators, including VB.NET syntax, are shown [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dscyy5s0.aspx?cs-lang=vb)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) interface.

Also, check out [Iterators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx) in .Net and the `yield` keyword, available in VB.Net from VS2012 and up.

Comment: Thanks I use Visual Studio 2010, so Iterators are not available.  Do developers implement their own Iterators as shown in the first link from the OP or do you tend just to do the easier thing of exposing the underlying object?

Comment: @w0051977 well, more generally: they either use C# (where iterator blocks have been available since 2005), or (for VB) they use a more recent version of the language that supports iterator blocks. Writing them by hand is not productive. The "express" editions are free... just saying...

Comment: @Rik "specifically VB.NET" (from question) - it isn't "since 2005"

Comment: Ah, yes, forgot about the VB.Net bit.